# Місцевий відмінок слова "парк"

Tags: відмінювання

Неодноразово чула, що кажуть "у паркУ" з наголосом на другий склад. Такий варіант є вірним?

Знайшла таблицю, в якій сказано, що наголос має бути на "а".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Правильний варіант наголосу на перший склад.

[Запам'ятаємо наголоси](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine8-11.pdf)

> Чуємо  - (у) парку́, а треба - (у) па́рку

[Словник відмінків](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Згідно до [цього сайту](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/words/conjugation/search/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA&lang=uk), на якому можна провідміняти будь-яке українське слово і подивитися його наголос у тому чи іншому відмінку, єдиним правильним варіантом буде: у пАрку.